# Closest value join with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a left table

[image]

and a right table

[image]

And I would like to get the final table

[image]

For this, I would like to use a function (merge or other more advanced verions like merge_asof or merge_ordered) in pandas

- the match for v1 and v2 is exact
- then the match for v3 is approximate, with the closest values.

Comment: you may want to define `closest`, how far off can it be?  What if there is only one match?

Comment: I just want only one match. for example, in the example, the closest value to 11 is 10. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `merge_asof`

```
out = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('v3'),
                    df2.sort_values('v3'), 
                    by = ['v1','v2'], 
                    on = 'v3', 
                    direction = 'nearest')

Out[10]: 
  v1 v2  v3    c
0  a  c  11  100
1  a  d  22  200
2  b  c  33  200
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa):

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, by=['v1', 'v2'], on='v3', direction='nearest')
```

*NB. 'v3' must be sorted in both `df1`/`df2`, if this not the case add `.sort_values('v3')`.*